# Oracle XML DB Annotations

Tags: xml, oracle11g

I have registered one `XSD` in oracle `XMLDB`.
Also I have annotated one element as a `CLOB` as shown below.

```
    <xs:element name="data" xdb:SQLType="CLOB">
        <xs:complexType>
           <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                 <xs:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
              </xs:extension>
           </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
```

Now when I insert a big doc (305 KB) for the same it shows that the insert is successful.

But when it is retrieved by the `OCCI` client application size of doc retrieved is truncated.

The behavior is proper for small size document.

Maybe there is problem in data being inserted.
I am not able to find what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the XSD to

```
  <xs:element name="data" xdb:SQLType="CLOB">
    <xs:simpleType>
     <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="31245"></xs:maxLength>
     </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
```

Now things seems to be working even if I do not know the root cause why it is so!